# selenium webdriver function driver.get("string") does not respond because of window authentication popup

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium 2.40 and java 6.

I searched a lot for a solution for handling windows authentication popup window.

I found some answers like using `Robot` ,`Alert` and `AutoIT`.

But actually none of these are working for me because after the following line ,nothing is getting executed even println

```
  public class ViewStudentsPage {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://stgmossfe01/";
    System.out.println("******************TEST***********1");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("******************TEST***********2");

  }

  @Test
  public void testViewStudentsPage() throws Exception {

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/Pages/default.aspx");
         System.out.println("******************TEST***********3");
         Robot robot;
         robot = new Robot();

         robot.delay(5000); 
         System.out.println("******************TEST***********4");
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); 
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); 
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M); 
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I); 
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N); 

         robot.delay(5000); 

         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);    

         robot.delay(5000); 

         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         System.out.println("******************TEST***********5");

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.MenuTasks > span")).click();
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [mouseOver | xpath=/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span | ]]
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [mouseOver | xpath=/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/span | ]]
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
  }
```

The driver never responds and i cannot do any further action.

Any ideas??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Pass authentication information while loading the url something like the below:

```
driver.get("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<url>") # e.g. driver.get("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@www.domainname.com")
```

Comment: Dear sitamj,Thanks for your reply but i cannot use this option since it wont work with IE

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing the authentication information using this code:

```
driver.get("http://<VALID USERNAME>:<VALID PASSWORD>@<VALID URL>")
```

**for example:**  `driver.get("http://admin:password@www.authenticationtest.com")`

Or you can use following JAVA ROBOT class code:

> I am assuming your username and password is admin/password

```
Robot robot;
robot = new Robot();

robot.delay(5000); 

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N); 

robot.delay(5000); 

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);    

robot.delay(5000); 

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

after your code:  `driver.get(url);`

Comment: Dear Abishek,I tried the robot (please see my first post updated) but as i mentioned before nothing is executed after driver.get(url) even the println.so this does not work for me.For the other solution i cannot use since i know it will not work with IE and i need to run the code on IE too.

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot once?